# A thread variable is set to null implicitly for some reason

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

My class uses 3rd party library classes to do a job. Generally I initialise the 3rd party library class, which in turn triggers a callback method:

```
public class MyJob {

     private Thread myThread;
     private ThirdPartyService mThirdParty;

     public MyJob() {…}

      public void start() {
     //get an instance of 3rd party class
           mThirdParty = ThirdParty.getInstance();

           //create an instance of 3rd party callback
           ThirdPartyCallBack callback = new ThirdPartyCallBack() {
                 @Override
                 public void onInitSuccess() {
                      if (null == myThread) {
                           myThread = new Thread();
                           System.out.println(“myThread is created in callback!”);

                           //do tasks…
                      }
                 }
           };

          System.out.println(“mThirdParty.init() …”);
          mThirdParty.init(callback);

          //myThread is null here when call start() the 2nd time, why?
          if (myThread == null) {
               System.out.println(“After mThirdParty.init(), myThread is NULL!”);
          } else {
               System.out.println(“After mThirdParty.init(), myThread is NOT NULL!”);
          }
      }

      public void stop() {
            myThread.join();
            myThread = null;
            System.out.println(“stopped!”);
       }
}
```

As you see above, the `mThirdParty.init(callback)` triggers the callback method `onInitSuccess()` be executed.

The code uses MyJob class:

```
MyJob job = new MyJob();
job.start();
Thread.sleep(5000);
job.stop();
Thread.sleep(5000);
job.start();
```

I first time start the job, every thing is fine here, the console prints the following logs:

```
mThirdParty.init() …
myThread is created in callback!
After mThirdParty.init(), myThread is NOT NULL!
```

after 5 seconds, I call stop(), log shows:

```
stopped!
```

after 5 seconds, start job again, log shows:

```
mThirdParty.init() …
myThread is created in callback!
After mThirdParty.init(), myThread is NULL!
```

Why after I start the job the 2nd time, I got myThread is NULL ? Could it be that the 3rd party library has implicitly set it to null in some way?

Comment: How about you look into the source code of the 3rd party library?

Comment: is this the real code? because `myThread = new Thread();` is useless. or did you make a class called Thread in your project?

Comment: it is not real code, I just try to show the general logic of my code

Comment: I just want to make sure it sounds like a 3rd party library doing something implicitly.

Comment: But it's not doing anything implicitly. So you're trying to make sure it sounds wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the "3rd party library" is your own code.

```
public void stop() {
        myThread.join();
        myThread = null;
        System.out.println(“stopped!”);
   }
```

You set it to null when you call stop().

---

Seems like you have memory synchronization problems. Add `volatile` to `myThread`.

`private volatile Thread myThread`

Comment: But if you see the log message carefully, `myThread` is created when call `job.start()`, I mean the callback initialize myThread always. I already see myThread is initialized, then the following log shows me myThread is null again. That's the thing I don't understand.

Comment: Same problem after adding `volatile`

Comment: Thanks, but real code is too large to show here. I will try to figure out by myself then.